# can't install simple_captcha produces uninitialized constant Sprockets::Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, captcha

I have included the simple_captcha gem as instructed on their site:

```
gem 'simple_captcha', :git => 'git://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha.git'
```

I have then run bundler to install it.

Finally when I go to run the following command I get an error:

```
 rails generate simple_captcha

.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@eapi4/bundler/gems/simple-captcha-e99cc7e8bf6b/lib/simple_captcha/form_builder.rb:7:in `included': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Helpers (NameError)
```

I've searched on the web and can't find any other users with this problem.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could it just be an outside dependency?  like this?  https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-helpers

Comment: It also says you need to install http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php . Did you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They say in  [this pull request](https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha/pull/39) that the plugin doesn't support rails 4, You can download their branch and try it out.

Looking at the diff it shows your problem

```
-      base.send(:include, Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper)
-      base.send(:include, Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper)
+      base.send(:include, Sprockets::Rails::Helper)
```

https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha/pull/39/files

Comment: Thanks that must be it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction it was driving me crazy

Answer (score 3):

you could this as the previous version of simple_captcha is not supported on rails 3.

[Azdaroth forked of simple_captcha](https://github.com/Azdaroth/simple-captcha/tree/rails-4)

```
gem 'simple_captcha', :git => 'git://github.com/Azdaroth/simple-captcha.git', :branch => 'rails-4'
```